# Wildfly 18 Jackson2 ObjectMapper ignored

Tags: wildfly, jackson2

I have this ObjectMapper configuration:

```
@Provider
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfig() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .findAndRegisterModules()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

with the following in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

ObjectMapper is not used. But when I remove `<scope>provided</scope>`, everything works as expected.

This is with Wildfly 18.0.1.

Am I missing something here?